# Invalid cast exception while querying 'time' field with NHibernate

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate

I have a complex query executed with Nhibernate using session.CreateSQLQuery.
And during execution I got the next exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

It seems that NHibernate can't correctly handle field type 'time' and expects integer value there. It works fine with regular HQL query over entity mapped using xml mapping file. However in my case I need to run an sql query, so it's not possible to specify mapping. Any ideas how to fix it? Looks like an NHibernate bug.

NHibernate verison: 3.3.1.4

Here is the full stack trace:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type
>   'System.IConvertible'.    at System.Convert.ToInt64(Object value)
>   at NHibernate.Type.TimeSpanType.Get(IDataReader rs, Int32 index) in
>   p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Type\TimeSpanType.cs:line 32 Inner
>   Exception: Input string '08:00:00' was not in the correct format.
>   at NHibernate.Type.TimeSpanType.Get(IDataReader rs, Int32 index) in
>   p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Type\TimeSpanType.cs:line 36    at
>   NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, String name)
>   in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Type\NullableType.cs:line 253
>   at
>   NHibernate.Loader.Custom.CustomLoader.ScalarResultColumnProcessor.Extract(Object[]
>   data, IDataReader resultSet, ISessionImplementor session) in
>   p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Loader\Custom\CustomLoader.cs:line
>   458    at
>   NHibernate.Loader.Custom.CustomLoader.ResultRowProcessor.BuildResultRow(Object[]
>   data, IDataReader resultSet, Boolean hasTransformer,
>   ISessionImplementor session) in
>   p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Loader\Custom\CustomLoader.cs:line
>   395    at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor
>   session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) in
>   p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 473    at
>   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor
>   session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) in
>   p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 251    at
>   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session,
>   QueryParameters queryParameters) in
>   p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 1564 could not
>   execute query [query]    at
>   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session,
>   QueryParameters queryParameters) in
>   p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 1573    at
>   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.ListIgnoreQueryCache(ISessionImplementor
>   session, QueryParameters queryParameters) in
>   p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 1472    at
>   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.ListCustomQuery(ICustomQuery customQuery,
>   QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results) in
>   p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionImpl.cs:line 2104    at
>   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(NativeSQLQuerySpecification spec,
>   QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results) in
>   p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionImpl.cs:line 2091    at
>   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List[T](NativeSQLQuerySpecification spec,
>   QueryParameters queryParameters) in
>   p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionImpl.cs:line 2078    at
>   NHibernate.Impl.SqlQueryImpl.ListT in
>   p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\SqlQueryImpl.cs:line 160

**UPDATE:**
Here is simple code that helps to reproduce the problem. TimeValue has 'time(0) null' type in sql server.

```
ISession session = TransactionScopeManager.Instance.GetSession();
iQuery = session.CreateSQLQuery("select TimeValue from TestTable");
result =  iQuery.List();
```

Comment: Maybe the bug is in your code? We can't tell since you don't show mappings and query. :)

Comment: There is no mapping involved since I'm using sql query. But I've added code which demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 1):

I am encountering the same error. A temporary solution I used is to cast the "Time" as "Varchar" first and parse the string to "TimeSpan" type in the code instead.

```
iQuery = session.CreateSQLQuery("select cast(TimeValue as varchar) as TimeStr from TestTable");
result =  iQuery.List();
```